# Possible iron/protein defeciency in vegetarians

Tags: diet, vegetarianism, supplement, iron

- Is it possible for vegetarians who eat plenty of dairy food to have iron or protein deficiency?
- Are there other demonstrable health benefits from eating small amounts of shellfish? Or is there evidence it can be bad for health in the way red meat can be?
- Is it still the case that there is little or no evidence that taking dietary supplements is an effective way of remedying iron or vitamin deficiency?

I am a biologist, and would appreciate some scientific explanation and references/evidence in answers if possible.

The questions https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-should-ovo-lacto-vegetarians-compensate-the-lack-of-meat-in-their-diets has some useful information, but does not contain anything about seafood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is it possible for vegetarians who eat plenty of dairy food to have iron or protein deficiency?**

Everyone who consumes too little iron can develop iron-deficiency anemia, but this is not necessary more common in vegetarians than in omnivores.

> An appropriately planned well-balanced vegetarian diet is compatible
>   with an adequate iron status. Although the iron stores of vegetarians
>   may be reduced, *the incidence of iron-deficiency anemia in vegetarians
>   is not significantly different from that in omnivores* ([PubMed,
>   1994](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8172127)).

It is a blood test that can reveal the presence and severity of anemia. It may be unreliable to estimate anemia from symptoms.

Dairy is not a good source of iron; an egg contains 0.88 mg, 50 g of most cheeses less than 0.30 mg, and a cup of milk (237 mL) only 0.15 mg ([USDA.gov](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report?nutrient1=303&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&fg=1&max=25&subset=1&offset=0&sort=c&totCount=68&measureby=m)). Calcium and phosphate from milk can significantly reduce the absorption of iron ([AJCN](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article-abstract/29/10/1142/4617100)). There are plant foods that contain much more iron, up to 6 mg per serving ([Chart 2, NutrientsReview](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/minerals/iron.html)).

Protein deficiency in vegetarians who regularly eat protein-containing foods is very unlikely ([PubMed, 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29786804)).

> There is a widespread myth that we have to be careful about what we
>   eat so that we do not cause protein deficiency. We know today that it
>   is virtually impossible to design a calorie-sufficient diet, whether
>   it is based on meat, fish, eggs, various vegetarian diets or even
>   unprocessed whole natural plant foods, which is lacking in protein and
>   any of the amino acids.

**Are there demonstrable health benefits from eating small amounts of shellfish? Or is there evidence it can be bad for health in the way red meat can be?**

Certain shellfish contain 2-8 mg of iron per serving ([USDA.gov](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=303&fg=15&subset=1&sort=c&measureby=m)). They also contain quite some protein, vitamin B12 and omega-3 fatty acids ([USDA.gov](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/15159?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=mollusk&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=)). It seems they contain less mercury than fish ([FDA.gov](https://www.fda.gov/food/metals/mercury-levels-commercial-fish-and-shellfish-1990-2012)). Rarely, shellfish poisoning can occur; this mainly depend on the location of their origin ([Canadian Food Inspection Agency](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/fact-sheets-and-infographics/products-and-risks/fish-and-seafood/toxins-in-shellfish/eng/1332275144981/1332275222849)). Shellfish are often considered a healthier food choice than red meat ([Dietary Guidelines for Americans, 2015, p.24](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015/resources/2015-2020_dietary_guidelines.pdf)); no food is healthy as such, though.

**Is it still the case that there is little or no evidence that taking dietary supplements is an effective way of remedying iron or vitamin deficiency?**

Supplements *are* an effective way to treat iron or other mineral or vitamin deficiencies. In a diagnosed deficiency, prescribed rather than commercially available supplements may be needed. [Linus Pauling Institute](https://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/minerals/iron) has a detailed article about iron, including iron supplements, anemia, foods high in iron, etc. *Individuals who are not at risk of iron deficiency should not take iron supplements without an appropriate medical evaluation to avoid iron overload.*

Healthy people without nutrient deficiencies will unlikely benefit from dietary supplements ([PubMed, 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3309636/)).

Comment: I'd go with a stronger wording of your last sentence: healthy people without nutrient deficiencies *should avoid* iron dietary supplements.  Iron has one of the narrowest gaps between "recommended consumption" and "overdose" of any nutrient.

Comment: I added that...